# How To Create A MYSQL tabe with php in which we can set the table name from a mysql database value(user session)?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to create a mysql table with php in which i can set the table name from a table column value of the particular user of a mysql database. in the below code i have tried to do that by equating the table name with a variable which stores the name(from database) but every time i get error means its not working please help me!

```
   <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect2.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
  header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

if($userRow['tableid']!=1)
{
    $user_id = $userRow['user_id'];

    $createtable="  CREATE TABLE `id`='$user_id' (
                        `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
                        `topic` int(5) NOT NULL,

                        `ptopic` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
                        ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

                    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
    $resulttid = mysqli_query($con, $createtable);
    if($resulttid)   {
        $tablequery = "UPDATE `users` SET `tableid`='1' WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";      
        $resulttblquery = mysqli_query($con, $tablequery); 
    }else{ 
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This sounds like you are aiming at a very bad database design. I cannot see any good reason for having a table for each user. What if you get a MILLION users

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: use `mysqli_error` to get the error message

Comment: create table is incorrect, try looking at examples here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-table/

Comment: `CREATE TABLE id='$user_id' (` is not valid Syntax change to `CREATE TABLE $user_id (`

Comment: @Jens ok..but how to set the table name like that ..what I want

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Although ew are not supposed to recommend tutorials I suggest you do at least one on Database Design before you proceed with the database design you appear to be targeting

Comment: @Jens it's not working

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you sir for your suggestions ..but I want to try that...

Comment: @RiggsFolly please tell me how to set the table name from a database value

Comment: Look at the MYSQL manual and check the syntax for a `CREATE TABLE` all you need to do is follow the correct syntax

Comment: First HARDCODE a full table create in your PHP. When that works, just replace the right bits with the variables from wherever

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have checked sir but I didn't found any example where we can set the table name from a variable

Answer (score 0):

Replace you create table code with below code so you can create table name form PHP variable And make sure Unquoted table names can consist of any alphanumeric characters in the server's default character set

```
$createtable=" CREATE TABLE $user_id(
                    `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
                    `topic` int(5) NOT NULL,
                    `ptopic` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

                ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
```